# How to properly configure sendmail to delivery message?

Tags: sendmail

I bought a VPS from OVH.

This Ubuntu VPS hostname is something like `vps12345` or `vps12345.ovh.net`.

If I test sendmail via command line to send an email to my mail test@gmail.com, it works: I receive an email from `test@vps12345@ovh.net`.

But I'd like to send mail from my installed domain (for instance: `test@mytestdomain.com`), and if test from my PHP code, mail sent to Gmail arrives but with a lot time late.

So I suppose that Gmail (or anyother email provider) don't accept emails with header from X domain, but from an hostname Y...

So how can I send email from my vps12345 using other domain (which I own and host on that VPS)?

Do I need to rename VPS hostname?

Thanks

Comment: "sendmail" can be installed directly or symlinked to a different MTA you have installed (for example postfix or exim). Check which MTA you have installed, find a tutorial for it and configure it. When you run into concrete problems, post them here including your configuration files and actual error messages you receive.

Answer (score 2):

**Proper way:** change host FQDN (fully quallified domain name) as reported by `hostname` command (typically `hostname --fqdn`).  The exact procedure may by OS/Distribution dependand.

**Sendmail only fix**: ["who am I" in cf/README](https://www.sendmail.org/%7Eca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/whoami.html) file in sendmail distribution.
=>define `confDOMAIN_NAME` in sendmail.mc file and generate new sendmail.cf
(submit.cf may also require changes).